# Array program average

Tags: arrays

So I'm new to java and I've been trying to get this program to work for about a day now. My hope is to have this program output something like this:

Please enter the number of digits you wish to find the average of : 4

Enter the 4 numbers: 2
5
8
10

The array is: 2 5 8 10

The average is: 6.25

The numbers above average are: 2

...Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int TOTAL_NUMBERS = 410;
    int[] numbers = new int[TOTAL_NUMBERS];
    int sum = 0;
    double mean = 0.0;
    double max = 0.0;
    for (int userNum = 0; userNum < numbers.length; userNum++) {

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of digits you wish to find "
                 + "the average of: ");
        userNum = scan.nextInt();

        //Calculate sum
        if (numbers[userNum] > max) {
            max = numbers[userNum];
        }

        sum += numbers[userNum];//the sum

         System.out.println("please enter " + userNum + " numbers");
    }



    //Calculate average
    mean = sum / numbers.length;

    String output = "The array is ";

    for (int userNum = 0; userNum < numbers.length; userNum++) {
        output += numbers[userNum] + " ";

    }

    output += "\nThe mean is: " + mean;

    System.out.println(output);

    String out = "The numbers above average are ";

    for (int userNum = 0; userNum < TOTAL_NUMBERS; userNum++) {

        if (numbers[userNum] > mean)//removed the ";"
        {

            out += numbers[userNum] + " ";

        }
    }

    System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: The code above is my attempt at the code, something is wrong with the first for loop, I can't figure it out

Comment: I don't think you are taking the right approach to learning. Take little steps and make sure each small step works before you move on to the next. From what you have, all you can hope for is to just receive a complete solution to what seems to be a homework assignment - but it will be very hard to learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sum_Average
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n, sum = 0;
        float average;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the number of digits you wish to find " 
        + "the average of: ");

        n = s.nextInt();

        int a[] = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter all the elements:");

        for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
        {
            a[i] = s.nextInt();
            sum = sum + a[i];
        }
        System.out.println("The array is  : ");

        for (int i=0;i < n; i++){
            System.out.println(a[i]+" ");
        }

        average = (float)sum / n;

        System.out.println("The average is : "+average);

        int numAbvAvg = 0;

        for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
            if(a[i]>average)numAbvAvg = numAbvAvg+1;
        }

        System.out.println("The numbers above average are: "+numAbvAvg);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone.